# patent conflicts

Tags: prior-art-request, novelty, conflict-of-interest

In reference to the patent: [WO2015130230A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2015130230A1)

Does this patent conflict with the following patents:

“一种在水体中原位取样、分离、富集、测量水体污染物的方法” with Nos. CN101021514 B, CN200710010550.1， CN200710010553.5，and  CN200710010554.X etc.  in China?

Comment: What do you mean by conflict?

Answer (score 0):

If by conflict you mean that WO2015130230A1 claims subject matter which can be found in the chinese patents and patent applications, I would say no, because the search report of the WO2015130230A1 would have them cited. The International Search report will cite any relevant document which was disclosed to the public **before the date of filing** of the WO2015130230 (or priority date). As suggested below in the comments, the search performed by a patent examiner is not always complete, but it is a good starting point. In this case, the prior art you are referring to are chinese patent documents. From my experience, I would not expect a (japanese!) patent examiner to miss them.

I had a look at  CN101021514B and CN101021515B. As far as I can see, the general idea appears to be the same, but they use different polymers and/or different solutions to collect the samples. This seems to be a big difference to me.

I can't say more, because I don't know Chinese :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  for your info, the above cited china patents are with english abstract which provide key patent contents.

Comment: @chempatent1981 - you might want to amend your answer. Examiners are not perfect and there may very well be prior art that the examiner did not cite. One of the functions of this site is to help people find such art.

Comment: https://encrypted.google.com/patents/CN101021515A?cl=en

Comment: Phosphorus fixing film applied to diffusive gradients in thin-films measurement technology 
CN 101629881 B

Comment: @GeorgeWhite you are correct in general, examiners do miss prior art occasionally. I responded in a simplified way, because the question was comparing two patent documents and examiners rarely miss such prior art based on patent literature. They usually miss scientific papers. But I will amend to a more detailed answer, it might be more useful.

Answer (score -1):

Method for in-situ sampling, separating enriching and measuring heavy metal ion in water body 
CN 101021515 A
ABSTRACT
A method to sample in situ, separate, enrich and measure heavy metal ion in waters. Its steps contain: (1) Puts some high-molecular compound being capable of occurring chemical reaction with heavy metal ion into device and uses a semi-permeable membrane being able to permeate heavy metal ion to cover it. (2) Puts device into waters and detaches it from waters by membrane. (3) Sets in waters for a period of time. Recur to osmosis of membrane, heavy metal ion enters into back of device to occur chemical reaction with high-molecular compound. (4) Takes out device located in waters to measure concentration and mean concentration of heavy metal in waters by atomic absorption spectrometry. It is characterized in that simple, economical, providing concentration and measurement in situ for much heavy metal, has selectivity.

Comment: another china patent, CN 201210208540, for phosphorus and sulphur measure, which uses the same principle and mechanism including a diffusive membrane and a binding phase.